# How to properly handle many domain commands sent to bounded context from UI?

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design, strapi

I am currently developing an application builded with 3 blocks - Strapi CMS, API Backend written in .NET 5 and custom UI.

I made a choice to use DDD approach and here is where my problem comes. Sometimes aggregates are modified from CMS admin panel, but it allows me to send HTTP call only on 'Save' click. Strapi allows me to use [its lifecycle hooks](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#models), however changes made there have different impact on my model in the API. Let's say I have course with below properties `Start date` and `Slot limit`. When I e.g. decrease `Slot limit` and change `Start date` and save both changes by submitting 'Save' button, not only must I violate rule of saving two aggregates by one UI command (`Start date` modified in `Course` aggregate and many `CourseSlot` entries being removed, but it may lead to lack of consistency - what if first operation has succeeded and the other none?

I thought about some orchestrating mechanism on server side that would order somehow operations and perform rollback in case of any modification failure, but still one problem remains - from Strapi I can only send plain json with current data, so I must detect somehow which domain commands it actually reflects. How may I solve this problem?